# list pages by custom_field?

Tags: custom-field, sort

Is there a way for me to sort these posts alphabetically according to the custom field I have defined (last_name)?

```
<?php
$page_id = get_the_ID();

$args = array('sort_order'=>'DESC', 'post_type'=>'page', 'child_of'=>$page_id, 'post_status'=>'publish');
$posts_array = get_pages($args);


foreach ($posts_array as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);
    ?>
    <li>
        (post content here)
    </li>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this help. If you use normal wordpress loop to query post or pages then you can do this by using query_posts

You need to place a line of query_posts before the loop start and it might look something like this ( you might need to add some more parameter for getting only pages in your case )

```
query_posts($query_string. '&order=DESC&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=last_name')
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: hmmm... i tried putting that before the loop and it makes the page return nothing. is there something i'm missing?

Comment: ok; i had it in the wrong place. it needs to come after the main page loop becaues this is actually a landing page that pulls in a list of the children pages. this list of children pages is what has to be sorted alphabetically by the custom field value. it is doing nothing when i put it before the $page_id variable.